# How do i get data-bind value in jquery

Tags: jquery, .net, knockout.js

I have a API controller class and it bounded to one of my view. The code given below

```
<a class="voteArrowup"  onclick="vote('up');" data-bind="attr: {id:PostId}" >^</a>
```

On "voteArrowup" click i need to get the anchor tag id attribute value in jquery. How do i do that?

Jquery

```
function vote(voteIcon) {
var postId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert('On click' + postId);
}
```

Comment: Don't mix jquery with Knokcout! Just use the `click` binding to handle the click event!

Comment: why mix inline script, jQuery and knockout? ... what a mess to maintain

Comment: I was little late to come across this link http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html which explains knockout "click" binding. Thanks nemesv and charliet for notifying about Knockout click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your replies. I got my answer by using the following code.

```
<a class="voteArrowup"  onclick="vote('up',this);" data-bind="attr: {id:PostId}" >^</a>
```

and then in my jquery i added some thing like this

```
function vote(voteIcon, elem) {
  var postId = $(elem).attr('id');
}
```